# How to plot SVM on R with multiple variables intake?

Tags: r, plot, svm

I am using the e(1071) library to perform a SVM 2 class classification. I will be running the SVM firstly with all of the 117 variables of my database, and then with only 10 best predictors (I know which those are after a random forest analysis, but it would be nice to know also how to find those through a SVM function).

For reference, this is my code:

```
reshuffle <- WplR[sample(nrow(WplR)),]
traindata <- reshuffle[1:500,]
testdata <- reshuffle[501:nrow(WplR),]

x <- traindata[,-118] #object with predictors
y <- traindata[,118]  #object with 2 classes

bstsvm <-svm(pop_vote~., data = traindata, cost = 0.01, kernel="linear")

pred <- predict(bstsvm, testdata[,-118])
confusionMatrix(pred, testdata[,118])

classificationtable = table(pred, testdata$pop_vote)
accuracy = sum(diag(classificationtable))/sum(classificationtable)

plot(x = bstsvm, data = testdata, fill = TRUE, grid = 50, slice = list(),symbolPalette = palette(), svSymbol = "x", dataSymbol = "o")
```

The plot function needs 'formula' input to address what to display as x axis and y axis, and thus, I have now 2 questions:

- How to plot as nicely as possible my svm? In other words, how could I clearly see the classification in 'pop_vote' and 'lib_vote' in a plot?
- How to plot the same nice classification while operating with just 10 variables?

I thought I might create 2 bigger indicators to measure intensity of pop_vote and intensity of lib_vote but that does seem a dangerous path.

Thanks in advance.